# Working with OpenAI, Embeddings and Tensorflow

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, openai-api

So I'm working on an "expert chatbot." The plan is to create embeddings for all the document sections, and then finetune the model with each of those sections. When the user asks a question, I get an embedding for the question, do this black-magic voodoo shit called dot-product against the embeddings from each of my sections, and the one with the most points wins.  Then I tell openAI to answer the question based on the matching section that I have loaded with the fine-tunes.  Easy peasy, right?

Except I'm not getting the dot product.  Tensor flow is giving me grief.  Here's my code:

```
function begin(){

    
    for(let q = 0; q < questions.length; q++) {
        let question = questions[q];
        let answers = [];
        for(let s = 0; s < sections.length; s++) {
            let section = sections[s];

// problem in here somewhere ->

            let qtensor = Array(question.embedding);
            //qtensor = tf.tensor(qtensor);
            let stensor = Array(section.embedding);
            //stensor = tf.tensor(Array(stensor));

            let answer = new Answer();
            answer.score = tf.dot(qtensor,sensor);

// <-- problem is up there.

            answer.title = section.title;
            answers.push(answer);
        }
        answers.sort((a,b) => a.score - b.score);
        console.log("Q: " + q.text);
        console.log("A: " + answers[0].title);
    }
    console.log("Done!");
}
```

please and thank you.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with `javascript` or `tensors` before but there seems to be a bug in the loops: Isn't the `answers` list being redefined each time you iterate to the next question ? the line:

> let answers = [];

should have been put before you start iterating over the questions -- the first for loop.

Comment: It seems that multiple answers can exist on the same question and each `let answers = [];` line is initializing a new array for a new question before the items are being processed.